# If a JSON object is passed to a function in Javascript/QML, can I edit that and persist the value for the next time?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm relatively new to QML but have been working with the QT framework for almost a decade so I thought I could pick it up pretty quickly for my current role/job.  It appears I was wrong.  I have a code sample from work - can't give the whole thing due to well NDAs and such but basically episode data is passed as an object to a function in QML - something like:

```
function start(params, soundtrackModel, subtitleModel)
```

inside there, there's a bunch of constants derived from sub-objects in the params object so I presume to do an if conditional you need to compare constants - I don't know - but it's just observation so I'm taking the constant previously created showContentAdvisoryWarning and I created another pulling from params - hoping that if it's "undefined" it would be seen as "false", am I correct on that?  Also, I'm hoping that then changing params.contentAdvisoryWarningShown to true, will persist it to the next episode.

The task I need to do is whenever an episode of a series like say Walking Dead which is like X or R or serious rating of sorts, the first episode will show the warning - episodes 2+ will not.  I'm trying to figure out though - Will this persist it?  I can't find in the QML code any calls to start( which is where this code happens to be.  I hoped to have a solution Monday morning at our 8 or 9:15 morning meetings if someone's reading this.  Here's the additional code I put in and hoping it's reasonbly right but I have no way of debugging it or I'd do 'that' - sorry I'm so clueless.

```
if(showContentAdvisory)
        {
        if(!contentAdvisoryScreenShown)
            {
            params.contentAdvisoryScreenShown = true
            startVideoPlayer(params, soundtrackModel, subtitleModel, showContentAdvisory)
            }
        else
            startVideoPlayer(params, soundtrackModel, subtitleModel, false)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created the following example to show you the difference between `var obj` and `QtObject`. You will see the former will not signal property changes to `obj` when `obj.contentAdvisoryScreenShown`  is changed, however, we can see the changes if we read `obj` imperatively. The latter, the `QtObject` signals property changes to the `obj2`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    property var obj: ({ contentAdvisoryScreenShown : 1 })
    QtObject {
        id: obj2
        property int contentAdvisoryScreenShown: 1
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Text {
            text: "obj: " + JSON.stringify(obj)
        }
        Text {
            text: "obj2: " + JSON.stringify(obj2)
        }
        Text {
            id: result
        }
        Button {
            text: "start"
            onClicked: {
                start(obj);
                start(obj2);
                result.text = "obj: " +  JSON.stringify(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    function start(param) {
        param.contentAdvisoryScreenShown++;
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAC+XicjZLNboMwDMfvPIXFqQgJaRypdtg4dZrWIfYCaZq26SBBjumGKt59IVQIKpjqQ0Rs/3/+CLKsNBJklNWSf3tyco1SrQh1Ye7976zRNRnvkx0FXD2wVqGuBFIDF4agd+cEVlfgVi8Uvewv0mhsco5CqPykfxQk8ARt4KQZbXdnwelG6kzukw4SD44BLxX9g7VUJ2ndmeqiLlXf7AjOFD9pNBG3DIEbK6oY2u8h4Uv8jvM7I+tKwHeD+RDCW779iAyhVEd5aFbWHwz57WOgeIkUP4jqloTC1AXN5L/WRFrNFzfEkPxJRKu0sC8rLHIq6czluxnXy7F4Jth3F3Vl4Xm0vbn1TdXt3Uj9eagVJ2nH6qvaZ2NlMGrYOaLl3yMM1zda+wc4CtCA)

Comment: The params I know are set as properties but I don't understand QML enough to know much - or rather the project is huge - I'm used to smaller stuff as I just always preferred to type code to get my layout done.  I think I understand your example though.